# Azure terraform reports Missing resource instance key

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Terraform **module** like below

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test1"{
    count    = "${length(var.azurerm_resource_group_name)}"
    name     = "${element(var.azurerm_resource_group_name, count.index)}"
    location = "${element(var.azurerm_resource_group_location, count.index)}"
}
```

I have defined **output.tf** as like below

```
output "resource_gp" {
    value = "${azurerm_resource_group.test1[count.index]}"
}
```

For the same module, **variables.tf** is below:

```
variable "azurerm_resource_group_name" {
    type = "list"
    default = ["SimpleMoon-Terra"]
}
variable "azurerm_resource_group_location" {
    type = "list"
    default = ["Central US"]
}
```

Calling the module as like below:

```
variable "azurerm_resource_group" {

    default={
    name     = "simpletestrg"
    location = "Central US"
    }
}

# Create Resource Group
module "Test_Resource_Groups" {
    source ="../../Modules/Test_Resource_Groups"
    #name                ="${var.azurerm_resource_group.name}"
    #location            ="${var.azurerm_resource_group.location}"
}
```

However, I'm getting error like below:

```
Error: Missing resource instance key

  on ../../Modules/Test_Resource_Groups/output.tf line 2, in output "resource_gp":
   2:     value = "${azurerm_resource_group.test1.name[count.index]}"

Because azurerm_resource_group.test1 has "count" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    azurerm_resource_group.test1[count.index]
```

I'm unable to understand what the actual error is and how to have it rectified.

Comment: `var.azurerm_resource_group_name` this must be `var.azurerm_resource_group`? In the main.tf

Comment: I don't think so, I have added now variables.tf file for the module. Please check again. Ty

Comment: `azurerm_resource_group.test1` is a resource and not an exported attribute. What exported attribute are you attempting to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code snippet shown in your error message disagrees with the source code you shared for `outputs.tf`:

```
    value = "${azurerm_resource_group.test1.name[count.index]}" # in the error message
    value = "${azurerm_resource_group.test1[count.index]}"      # in the given source code
```

There are a few problems here, one of which is only in the source code shown in the error message:

- Because `azurerm_resource_group.test1` has `count` set, it appears in expressions as a list of objects. Therefore the first operation applied to it must be an index operation, giving an expression like `azurerm_resource_group.test1[count.index].name`: take the `name` attribute of the `count.index` element of the `azurerm_resource_group.test1` list.
- You can't use `count.index` inside an output value expression, because there is no `count` argument in scope there to know what `count.index` value to use. If you goal was to return a list of all of the names of all of the resource groups, you can write that as `azurerm_resource_group.test1[*].name`, which is a [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions).

In this particular case the value of `output "resource_gp"` will always be the same as the value of `var.azurerm_resource_group_name`, because the names are populated from there. However, such a reference via the resource *is* useful because it tells Terraform that anything that refers to that output value must in turn depend on `azurerm_resource_group.test1`, and thus helps ensure that all of the operations will be applied in an appropriate order.

---

There is a different way to write what you wrote here that will achieve a similar result on initial creation but will also work better for subsequent changes to `var.azurerm_resource_group_name`.

First, we will define the variable as being a map of objects so that we can use only a single variable to specify the resource groups.

```
variable "azurerm_resource_groups" {
  type = map(object({
    location = string
  }))
  default = {
    SimpleMoon-Terra = {
      location = "Central US"
    }
  }
}
```

We can then use [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) instead of [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) when defining the resource group:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test1"{
  for_each = var.azurerm_resource_groups

  name     = each.key
  location = each.value.location
}
```

As well as making the expressions simpler, this has another important effect: Terraform will identify the resource groups with addresses like `azurerm_resource_group.test1["SimpleMoon-Terra"]` rather than `azurerm_resource_group.test1[0]`, and so when you add and remove items from `var.azurerm_resource_groups` Terraform can keep track of which remote resource group object belongs to which element of the map.

`for_each` also causes `azurerm_resource_group.test1` to appear in expressions as a map rather than as a list, so we need to change the output `value` to work with that. Because the map keys are the resource group names, we can use [the `keys` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/keys.html) to obtain them. We'll also use [`toset`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/toset.html) to convert this to a set, reflecting that these are not in any particular order and so users of this value should not rely on the ordering:

```
output "resource_group_names" {
  value = toset(keys(azurerm_resource_group.test1))
}
```

Your calling module can then call this module as in the following example:

```
module "test_resource_groups" {
  source = "../../Modules/Test_Resource_Groups"

  azurerm_resource_groups = {
    simpletestrg = {
      location = "Central US"
    }
  }
}
```

In that calling module, references to `module.test_resource_groups.resource_group_names` will produce the set of resource group names, which can then be used with `for_each` elsewhere in the configuration to produce one object per resource group.

Comment: Truly amazing response. I'm yet to digest. I shall do more practice around this and ask if I need any further assistance.